# Major slowdown after upgrade to Symfony 3.1/3.2 (related to system cache)

Tags: php, caching, symfony, symfony-cache

After updating my application from Symfony 3.0.6 to Symfony 3.1.0, I noticed a major slowdown (more than double the time to load a single page) in development (xdebug disabled). The same can be observed with Symfony 3.2.0. This led me to believe that the issue might be caused by the new PSR-6 caching component introduced with Symfony 3.1.0, and the blackfire comparison seems to confirm that:

https://blackfire.io/profiles/compare/c9dd287a-c2aa-4b97-b335-635b08feac07/graph

This is my framework configuration for development (which I use in both 3.0.6 and 3.2.0):

```
translator:
    fallbacks: '%default_locale%'
    logging: false
secret:        '%secret%'
router:
    strict_requirements: true
form:            ~
csrf_protection: ~
validation:
    enable_annotations: true
    enabled:            true
templating:
    engines: [ twig ]
default_locale:  '%default_locale%'
trusted_proxies: ~
session:
    handler_id: snc_redis.session.handler
fragments:       ~
http_method_override: true
profiler:
    only_exceptions: false
```

I looked at the Symfony issue tracker but did not see anyone complaining about this. Also, the Symfony upgrade guide does not mention anything about framework configuration so I assume no changes are needed there.

NOTE: I'm not using the caching component for userland caching, in my case only the framework is relying on that.

Did anybody experience something similar?

Comment: I think you should report this issue at [Symfony repository](github.com/symfony/symfony/issues). That's the right place to do it